# finding relations between co-concurrent data

Tags: python, pandas, networkx, graph-databases

I have a dataframe that looks like graph database.

```
import pandas as pd
mycols=['china', 'england', 'france', 'india', 'pakistan', 'taiwan']

df=pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]], columns=mycols)

df.index=mycols
```

The simplified dummy dataframe looks like this:

```
           china    england france  india   pakistan    taiwan
china          0          0      0      3          0    0
england        0          0      1      1          0    0
france         0          1      0      1          0    0
india          3          1      1      0          1    0
pakistan       0          0      0      1          0    4
taiwan         0          0      0      0          4    0
```

Let's assume a user want to go from china to india, there is direct route.

```
df[df['china'] > 0].index.str.contains('india')
array([ True])
```

But no direct route to england:

```
df[df['china'] > 0].index.str.contains('england')
array([False])
```

In that case, I need to find the common country:

```
set(df[df.loc['china'] > 0].index.values) & set(df[df.loc['england'] > 0].index.values)
{'india'}
```

But there are cases where there is no common friend, and I need to find friend of friend to reach the destination. for e.g.

```
set(df[df.loc['china'] > 0].index.values) & set(df[df.loc['taiwan'] > 0].index.values)
```

1) In this case how do I write a query that will return china - india - pakistan - taiwan ?

2) Is there any better way to store this? Or SQL like (rows / columns) is ok?

Comment: Can you not load your database into `networkx` and use Dijkstra's algorithm to obtain the paths you want? The alternative likely involves reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/) in the following way

**Load the graph**

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
mycols=['china', 'england', 'france', 'india', 'pakistan', 'taiwan']

df=pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
   [3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 4],
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0]], columns=mycols)

#Load the graph from dataframe
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(df.values)

#set the nodes names
G = nx.relabel_nodes(graph, dict(enumerate(mycols)))
```

**Test if the graph is correctly loaded**

```
print G.edges()
#EdgeView([('pakistan', 'taiwan'), ('pakistan', 'india'), ('england', 'india'), ('england', 'france'), ('india', 'china'), ('india', 'france')])

print graph['china']
#AtlasView({'india': {'weight': 3}})

print graph['england']
#AtlasView({'india': {'weight': 1}, 'france': {'weight': 1}})
```

Now suppose you need to find all path from `china` to `india`

```
for path in nx.all_simple_paths(graph, source='china', target='taiwan'):
    print path
#Output : ['china', 'india', 'pakistan', 'taiwan']
```

If you want to find shortest paths from one node to another

```
for path in nx.all_shortest_paths(graph, source='taiwan', target='india'):
    print path
#Output : ['taiwan', 'pakistan', 'india']
```

You can find multiple other algorithms for finding the shortext path, all-pair shortest path, dijsktra algorithm, etc. [at their documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/shortest_paths.html?highlight=shortest%20path) to suit your queries

**Note** there might exist a way to load the graph directly from pandas using [from_pandas_dataframe](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html), but I was not sure if the use case was correct, as it requires a source and target

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (I am assuming) is basically to find the shortest path between any two given nodes in a weighted graph. Algorithmically speaking, this is called [Shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Single-source_shortest_paths) (or more precisely **single-pair shortest path problem**). Networkx 2.1 has a function [`shortest_path`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path) for exactly doing this

From their example,

```
G = nx.path_graph(5)
>>> print(nx.shortest_path(G, source=0, target=4))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> If the source and target are both specified, return a single list of
>   nodes in a shortest path from the source to the target.

If you want to get the get the shortest path to all the nodes from a source, just skip the `target` node (essentially making it a **single-source shortest path problem**)

Comment: There are several ways to load a graph in networkx. Probably this is the easier one since you have a dataframe already: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_adjacency.html

Comment: That is something [easily found with Google](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html). Also note that you might have to do a reverse aliasing (i.e. replacing columns with names), since graphs generally perform on IDs instead of named columns like Pandas.